# non-blocking connect() and select() with zero timeout is returning 0

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, posix, nonblocking

I'm writing a single-threaded app that handless several connected TCP sockets in a loop.
Here's the part where it initiates connection:

```
// Set up connecting socket
wire[wi].skt=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (wire[wi].skt==-1) return TEC_SOCK_ERR;
wire[wi].sai.sin_family=AF_INET;
memmove(&wire[wi].sai.sin_addr,&rconf.txaddr,sizeof(struct in_addr));
wire[wi].sai.sin_port=htons(rconf.txport);
// Initiate connection
int cres = connect(wire[wi].skt,(struct sockaddr *)&wire[wi].sai,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
// Comprehend results
if (cres==0)
{   // Connect already established
    wire[wi].state=CONNECTED;
    return 0;
};
if (cres==-1) // Socket error meaning depends on errno
    switch (errno)
    {
        // This is OK for non-blocking sockets
        case EINPROGRESS : {    // Connect initiated
                                wire[wi].state=CONNECTING;
                                return 0;
                            };
        default : return TEC_SOCK_ERR;
    };
return 0; // Should not normally happen
```

Obviously, `EINPROGRESS` is most often the case here, so then there's another code within a loop

```
            case CONNECTING :   {
                                    struct timeval tv;
                                    fd_set rfds;
                                    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
                                    FD_SET(wire[wc].skt,&rfds);
                                    memset(&tv,0,sizeof(struct timeval));
                                    int retval = select(1,NULL,&rfds,NULL,&tv);
                                    printf("%d:%d ",retval,errno);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    // Done
                                    break;
                                };
```

What I don't get is why `select` here always returns 0 and `EAGAIN`, regardless of whether the connection was successful or not.

I'm in a search for the most reliable way of telling if a connection was (not)successful on non-blocking socket.
Thanks in advance.

upd. It seems that there's no apparent mistakes, so I'll just do an MWE to eventually find it somewhere else as something stupid :)

Comment: Hmmm the variable name `rfds` implies "read file descriptors", however you are using them where `select()` expects the write file descriptors... that's suspicious to me.

Comment: @trojanfoe Poor naming, but correct code. A `connect()` completion triggers as a writable socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>       int retval = select(1,NULL,&rfds,NULL,&tv);
> ```

The first parameter of select is not the number of fds, but (from the linux man page):

> nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

Unless your socket has fd 0 (in which case you must have closed stdin) the value of 1 you use is wrong. This means that all of the fds in the set which are less than nfds (i.e. none) are ready and thus select returns 0. The code should be instead:

```
       int retval = select(  1+wire[wc].skt,  NULL,&rfds,NULL,&tv);
```

Comment: oh creep... O_O I remember myself reading that. Kind of counter-intuitive that is. Thanks anyway! At least one problem solved. Now that select returns 1, how do I know if sockets connected or failed?

Comment: If you want to pass in the number of socket descriptors, use `poll()` instead of `select()`. In any case, if `select()` returns 1, it means 1 socket descriptor satisfied the wait. Since you are only passing in 1 socket in a connecting state, by definition of `connect()` that means the connection was successful.  If the connection had failed, the socket would not become writable, it would be in an error state instead. Use the 4th parameter to `select()` to detect that.

Comment: `fd_set wfds, efds;
FD_ZERO(&wfds);
FD_ZERO(&efds);
FD_SET(wire[wc].skt,&wfds);
FD_SET(wire[wc].skt,&efds);
...
if (select(1+wire[wc].skt,NULL,&wfds,&efds,&tv) > 0)
{
    if (FD_ISSET(&wfds)) { /*connected*/ }
    else if (FD_ISSET(&efds)) { /*failed*/ }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `select()` 'regardless of whether the connection was successful or not'. You're only calling it in the EINPROGRESS case. If it returns zero, no FDs are ready, so the connection is still in progress.

Comment: But using `netstat -np | grep appname` I see that connection is established fine, yet select still returns zero.

Comment: So you managed to start this code, run `netstat,` and then see `select()` return zero? Really? It returned zero *after* you ran `netstat?` Really? In zero time? And why wasn't `netstat` mentioned in your question? In any case a connect timeout of zero isn't likely to be enough, is it? Try a second or two, or five.

Comment: I start the app, `connect()` is called, then the loop with `select()` starts and I see zeroes flooding; then I fire up `netstat` and it shows the connect is made (actually it is made to the netcat -vv on the same machine, so there's no way it couldn't be established by then). All this time `select()` returns zero.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm in a search for the most reliable way of telling if a connection was (not)successful on non-blocking socket.

Do a `recv` on the socket. If connected, `recv` would return -1 and you would get EAGAIN if there was nothing to be read. If the connection was not successful, `recv` would return 0.